# SQL Query Works, But Not In PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I tested and successfully used this SQL code below to input data into a database.

```
INSERT INTO hraps (id, firstname, lastname, gender, year_of_1st_rappel, count_offset_proficiency, count_offset_operational, spotter) values(111111, 'World', 'Hello', 'Male', '2007', '1', '2', '0')
```

Now I'm trying to integrate it into PHP like this:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO hraps (firstname, lastname, gender, year_of_1st_rappel, count_offset_proficiency, count_offset_operational, spotter) "
."values('".$this->firstname."','".$this->lastname."','".$this->gender."','".$this->year_of_1st_rappel."',".$this->count_offset_proficiency.",".$this->count_offset_operational.",".$this->spotter.") returning id into :id";

$dbid = "";
$binds = array();
$binds[] = array("name" => ":id", "value" => &$dbid, "length" => 128);
//echo $query;              
$result = mydb::cxn()->query($query, $binds);
$this->id = $dbid;
```

But nothing gets inserted and I'm not getting any error. The only difference is that in this one I'm defining id as $dbid, and before I hard-coded it in the "values" section of the query.

Can somebody please point out why this code is not working successfully?
Thank you.

Comment: 1st step: check your db connection works. We can't do this for you.

Comment: those queries aren't equal, in the first you insert '1','2',and '3' while in the second you insert 1,2,3

Comment: Error reporting is on? If you **SAY WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED** these questions wouldn't need to be asked.

Comment: Just this: "Warning: array_change_key_case(): The argument should be an array in...".

Comment: do `echo $query;` and check if the query is what you want it to be. And why are you not using prepared statements for ALL your values?

Comment: @navlag so, you get a warning, but in which file? On what line? Also, as John suggests, debug your $query to check if it is formatted correctly after inserting the variables (and **please** use prepared statements/binding to prevent SQL injection!)

Answer (score 1):

just remove `"."` before `VALUES` . try this

and you missed `mysqli_query()`

```
   $query= "INSERT INTO hraps (firstname, lastname, gender, year_of_1st_rappel, count_offset_proficiency, count_offset_operational, spotter) 
  values ('".$this->firstname."','".$this->lastname."','".$this->gender."','".$this->year_of_1st_rappel."',".$this->count_offset_proficiency.",".$this->count_offset_operational.",".$this->spotter.") returning id into :id ";
```

edit : if it Oracle then use this

```
    $compiled = oci_parse($db, $query); //-- $db is your connection to database variable
    oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':id', $id);  // --your id
    oci_execute($compiled);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, it's not mysql or mysqli, it's an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

The two queries above are not equal, as they use different data types (int v string).

The first casts as string, the second casts as int. Change the INSERT query to read:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO hraps (firstname, lastname, gender, year_of_1st_rappel, count_offset_proficiency, count_offset_operational, spotter) "
."values('".$this->firstname."','".$this->lastname."','".$this->gender."','".$this->year_of_1st_rappel."','".$this->count_offset_proficiency."','".$this->count_offset_operational."','".$this->spotter."') returning id into :id";`
```

Comment: Also, try echoing the DB error, just because PHP doesn't throw an error doesn't mean your database class or database itself did not.

Comment: This just crashes the site and causes and HTTP 500 error. Thanks though.

Comment: Interesting, the only DB errors I'm aware of causing 500 crashes are infinite requests, which typically happen when a primary key of 0 or false is used.